# Clear values loaded from a JSON file in a C# application

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have a C# very big C# application with a lot of values that are saved in a JSON file. At the very start, I can either do it fresh (i.e: choose new values as I enter in the values in the textboxes etc) or load an existing JSON file. There are no problems with either of that.

However, now what I want to be able to do is that if I load in an existing JSON file with said values, and if I go back then those values should be cleared up. Let me demonstrate all this more with examples.

So I have two modes- fresh and update. In fresh, I type in those values manually however in update, you are asked to upload a JSON file and then those values are loaded in their respective text boxes, check boxes etc.

As it stands now, if I have loaded in a JSON file and then I click "Back" to go to fresh mode, the values are not reset and my application loads in the values from the JSON file. I want to be able to clear those values and reset them. I don't know how to achieve this.

In the "browse" button where the user loads up the JSON file, I have this code:

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = ".json",
                Filter = "JSON Files (*.json)|*.json"
            };
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                Configs.ConfigPath = dlg.FileName;
                jsonFile.Text = dlg.FileName;
                string userJson = File.ReadAllText(Configs.ConfigPath);
                try
                {
                    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppConfigs>(userJson);
                    try
                    {
                        CopyNotNulls(json, Configs.Default);
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

For the xaml of the text box where you load in the json file, I have this `TextChanged` event arg and if I manually remove what the user has loaded and delete the text in that text box, then that works fine. But I want it done so that whenever I go back from that page, it resets when I go back from the update page to fresh page.

Comment: `private void Back_Click(...) { clear everything }` ? This question seems to be lacking a bit information about the mechanics of what you actually need

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the process of your application correctly you are loading the json file into an objet and the controls that display the data are bound to the object properties, right? the only thing you have to do to get rid of those values is to get a new object if you go the fresh route. Just do:

```
var json = new AppConfigs();
```

alternatively, if you want to keep some of the values you'd have to reset them, for example on the AppConfigs object you can add a public method that clears the fields you want to get rid of. That would look like this:

```
public class AppConfigs
{
    public string stringProp { get; set; }
    public bool boolProp { get; set; }
    public int intProp { get; set; }

    public AppConfigs()
    {
       // default values here
       // or just call Clear();
       stringProp = "";
       boolProp = false;
       intProp = 0;
       
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        stringProp = "";
        boolProp = false;
        intProp = 0;
    }
}
```

then you could call it on your button click:

```
json.Clear();
```